# How to move a projectile through positions in a given time regardless of the positions count

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to lerp a projectile through a list of positions in a certain time.

My code works when the positions count is not very high, **but when the list contains a thousand points**, the time that projectile takes is not the same, it clearly increases.

My code to move the projectile is the following:

```
public float timeToMove = 3;
public GameObject projectile;
public ParabolaDrawer parabolaDrawer; //this class generates the list of the points

private int currentPosIndex = 0;
private Vector3 currentPos = new Vector3();
private List<Vector3> parabolaPointsPositions = new List<Vector3>();
private bool hasArrivedToPos = false;
private bool hasArrivedToLastPos = false;

[ContextMenu("LaunchProjectile")]
private void LaunchProjectile()
{
    currentPosIndex = 0;

    hasArrivedToPos = false;
    hasArrivedToLastPos = false;
    
    parabolaPointsPositions = parabolaDrawer.parabolaPoints; //returns a List<Vector3>
    projectile.transform.position = parabolaDrawer.parabolaPoints.ElementAt(0);
    currentPos = projectile.transform.position;

    StartCoroutine(MoveProjectileThroughTheParabola(timeToMove));
}

private IEnumerator MoveProjectileThroughTheParabola(float timeToMove)
{
    float timeToMoveToNextPosition = timeToMove / (parabolaPointsPositions.Count - 1);
    float step = 0f;
    Vector3 initialPos = parabolaDrawer.initialPosition;

    while (step < 1 && !hasArrivedToLastPos)
    {
        // Move our position a step closer to the target.
        step += Time.smoothDeltaTime / timeToMoveToNextPosition; // calculate step distance to move in stablished time
        projectile.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(initialPos, currentPos, step);

        //Check if arrived to the point
        if (Vector3.Distance(projectile.transform.position, currentPos) <= 0.001f)
            hasArrivedToPos = true;

        if (hasArrivedToPos)
        {
            //Check which is the next point or if has arrived to the last one
            if (currentPosIndex == (parabolaPointsPositions.Count - 1))
                hasArrivedToLastPos = true;
            else
            {
                initialPos = currentPos;
                step = 0f;
                currentPosIndex++;
                currentPos = parabolaPointsPositions.ElementAt(currentPosIndex);
                hasArrivedToPos = false;
            }
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

My test was to set `timeToMove` to 3, and try to move the object through 1000 points in this 3 seconds, it takes 10.

I guess the problem lies on `deltaTime` being greater than `timeToMoveToNextPosition`, but I'm not sure how to fix it, should I calculate `currentPosIndex` on a different way?

*Edit: Providing info on @NSJacob1 answer*

If I'm understanding correctly, this is the final code using your method?

```
private IEnumerator MoveProjectileThroughTheParabola(float timeToMove)
{
    Vector3[] points = parabolaDrawer.GetParabolaPoints().ToArray();
    float elapsedTime = 0;
    float duration = timeToMove;
    while(elapsedTime < duration)
    {
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        float pathPosition = Time.deltaTime / duration;
        float indexPosition = pathPosition * points.Length;

        int left = Mathf.FloorToInt(indexPosition);
        int right = Mathf.CeilToInt(indexPosition);
        float t = indexPosition - left;

        Vector3 position = Vector3.Lerp(points[left], points[right], t);
        projectile.transform.position = position;
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

*Edit2: Keep improving with info from @NSJacob1 comments*

```
private IEnumerator MoveProjectileThroughTheParabola(float timeToMove)
{   
    Vector3[] points = parabolaDrawer.GetParabolaPoints().ToArray();
    elapsedTime = 0;
    duration = timeToMove;
    indexPosition = 0;
    pathPosition = 0;
    right = 0;
    left = 0;

    while (right < points.Length)
    {
        pathPosition = elapsedTime / duration;
        indexPosition = pathPosition * points.Length;

        left = Mathf.FloorToInt(indexPosition);
        right = Mathf.CeilToInt(indexPosition);

        if(right < points.Length)
        {
            t = indexPosition - left;
            position = Vector3.LerpUnclamped(points[left], points[right], t);
            projectile.transform.position = position;
        }
        else
        {
            projectile.transform.position = points.Last();
        }
        elapsedTime += Time.smoothDeltaTime;
        
        yield return null;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Try changing `float pathPosition = Time.deltaTime / duration;` to `float pathPosition = elapsedTime / duration;`. You may also want to consider applying some smoothing to the movement if it still seems jerky, and setting the position of the projectile to the final point after your `while` completes.

Comment: hi @NSJacob1 awesome approach, many thanks, but I still have troubles. I've modified the code with your ideas but the trajectory duration is 2.4 instead of 3, and 8 instead of 10, with less points, the difference between times is bigger, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason for your code to take much longer than your intended duration now, although `smoothDeltaTime` may introduce some delay depending on your frame variability. Maybe tomorrow I'll try running what you've got for myself and see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks @NSJacob1, if you wanna do the same test as I do, with this set of points the travel duration is 2 seconds instead of 3:
(0,0,0)
(3.768777,2.606755,1.976568)
(6.141703,3.53734,4.742089)
(7.118778,2.791757,8.296565)
(6.700002,0.3700044,12.64)

Comment: @NSJacob1 hi Jacob, could you try it? ^^ still having the same troubles :(

Comment: I whipped up a sample project using Cinemachine tracks for the spline track yesterday, and updated the code in my answer to match exactly. Here is the sample: https://gitlab.com/jthra037/lerp-over-array
Please read and follow up there in issues if you have more trouble. I believe I have answered your original question here.

Comment: @NSJacob1 Many thanks for your answer and your repo Jacob! But when I reduce your LerpAlongPath segments (to 10 or so) the cube do not reach the end, is the expected behaviour? I'm missing something? Many thanks again for carry my question on to this level!

Comment: When resolution is low, each step is large. The issue isn't with the Lerp, but rather with how I'm constructing the path (quickly and lazily). If your path ends where you want it to end, your object should continue to where you intend it to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move from point to point, you will get a lag based on the number of times you need to change sets of points.Try thinking instead about the whole set of points as a path and decide where, as a float from `[0, 1]`, you are along that path.

If the whole path is traversed in 3 seconds, and there are 1000 points, 1.5 seconds is 0.5f along our path, or point 500.

Here is an example:

```cs
private IEnumerator MoveProjectileAlongPath(float timeToMove)
{
    Vector3[] points = path;
    float duration = timeToMove;
    float start = Time.time;
    float elapsed = 0;
    // Time.deltaTime is the duration of a single frame,
    // so this will set position to "after one frame of movement"
    while (elapsed < duration )
    {
        elapsed = Time.time - start;
        float pathPosition = elapsed / duration; // our [0, 1] value
        float indexPosition = pathPosition * points.Length; // position in path

        int left = Mathf.FloorToInt(indexPosition);
        int right = Mathf.CeilToInt(indexPosition);
        if (right >= segments)
        {
            transform.position = path[points.Length - 1];
            break;
        }
        float t = indexPosition - left; // percent between left and right position

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(points[left], points[right], t);

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

If you track your previous path position or duration of time seen so far, you can build on each frame. Not by stepping toward a goal, but by figuring out where in the whole traversal you are and going there directly.

Comment: thanks for answering @NSJacbo1 but I've tested your method and I must be doing something wrong cause the projectile blinks but do not move, I've attached how I'm using your code on my question, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This code isn't intended to run "as is" but show the process I'm suggesting you implement. Hopefully the comments make the implementation of the idea a little clearer.